# Is Gandalf really to blame for Sauron's return?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In *The Hobbit*, Gandalf assembles the party of 13 to retake the Misty Mountain and give Erebor back to Thorin.  However, along the way, Bilbo and company are captured by goblins and Bilbo meets Golum.  There's no indication that anyone or anything actually knew of Golum's existence or location until Bilbo met him.

Yes, Sauron was already beginning his return, even without the one ring, but had Bilbo never found the ring and stolen it from Golum, it never would have returned to the surface.  So, by that logic, since Gandalf was so adamant about Bilbo being the dwarves' burglar and basically guilted him into joining them he is responsible for the ring being found. Had Bilbo stayed home, the ring would have stayed hidden with Golum.

**So, is Gandalf the person responsible for the events of the third age and Sauron's return to power?**

Comment: I'll leave it to the experts to answer, but canon is clear that life... err Ring "finds a way", to borrow a phrase from Jurassic Park.

Comment: Eventually even Gollum would have died and the Ring would have made its way into the hands of another person.

Comment: This seem to be less of a question and more of a rant. Who's to say that Bilbo or Déagol aren't equally to blame?

Comment: @Richard, no.  I'm asking, is Gandalf the one responsible.  The fact that I went into detail about the question is not a rant.

Comment: He's "responsible" in the sense that he was involved. Bilbo was the one who went and tricked poor Gollum out of his ring.

Comment: @DVK - They discussed burying it or hiding it at the Council Meeting. If memory serves, the consensus of opinion is that it would eventually emerge even if hidden carefully

Comment: Gollum gets captured, tortured and interrogated after losing the ring. I don't have a source, but that indicates that Sauron knew Gollum had the ring.

Comment: @Kevin but Gollum left the cave and wandered into Mordor after Bilbo stole the ring.

Comment: @Robert Still, he got captured and interrogated about the ring. Sauron must have suspected something to ask those questions.

Comment: @Kevin good point

Comment: @Kevin: Gollum was captured while he was nosing around in or near Mordor. It was during his *routine* interrogation that Sauron learned of his connection to the Ring, and thus about Bilbo.

Comment: My question is a duplicate of a question asked at a later date huh?  Starting to think that there's one or two people that have multiple accounts that just go around up-voting each other and flagging questions they like and wanted to, but didn't ask.

Comment: @Robert well yeah that first guy to flag it asked the other question.

Comment: @EricSSH I know, and that's my point.  That question is the exact same as mine, asked 2 days after mine, he even admitted it.  Which is why I seriously believe that he and the people that flagged this one are either the same person, or they all sit around together wrongly flagging questions and upvoting each other because look at any wrongly VTC'd question and it's the same group of people that did it and usually, there's un-constructive comments from those people.

Comment: @Robert There is precedence that [an older question gets closed as dupe of a newer one](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate). Also there were discussions about the question's closure and potential re-posting in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18840007#18840007). Had you not closed the question quickly, it may have been salvaged.

Comment: @Mooz you claim there's a precedence, yet this newer question is marked as a duplicate of a question asked after this one.  Care to explain that?

Comment: @Robert That's what the meta discussion is stating: that an **older** question can be closed as duplicate of a **newer** one. The issue here though, is that you closed your question, and re-opened once the newer one was asked. At the time of asking, the other question was not a duplicate. Like we tried to point out, the essence of the question was "good content" for this site as demonstrated by [this good answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73917/21267), just not the delivery of the question. Perhaps create a meta discussion in order to get a community consensus on this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. In fact, it was Sauron's rising that prompted Gandalf to find a way to re-take Erebor and remove Smaug from the possible use by Sauron.

LOTR, Appendix A *Annals of the Kings and Rulers*:

> But at last there came about by chance a meeting between Gandalf and
>   Thorin that changed all the fortunes of the House of Durin, and led to
>   other and greater ends beside. On a time Thorin, returning west from a
>   journey, stayed at Bree for the night. There Gandalf was also. He was
>   on his way to the Shire, which he had not visited for some twenty
>   years. He was weary, and thought to rest there for a while.
>     Among
>   many cares he was troubled in mind by the perilous state of the North;
>   because he knew then already that Sauron was plotting war, and
>   intended, as soon as he felt strong enough, to attack Rivendell. But
>   to resist any attempt from the East to regain the lands of Angmar and
>   the northern passes in the mountains there were now only the Dwarves
>   of the Iron Hills. And beyond them lay the desolation of the Dragon.
>   The Dragon Sauron might use with terrible effect. How then could the
>   end of Smaug be achieved?

If Bilbo had stayed home it's likely that the Ring would have been found by some Orc:

LOTR, Book I, Ch. 2 *The Shadow of the Past*:

> The Ring was trying to get back to its master. It
>   had slipped from Isildur’s hand and betrayed him; then when a chance
>   came it caught poor Déagol, and he was murdered; and after that
>   Gollum, and it had devoured him. It could make no further use of him:
>   he was too small andmean; and as long as it stayed with him he would
>   never leave his deep pool again. So now, when its master was awake
>   once more and sending out his dark thought from Mirkwood, it abandoned
>   Gollum. Only to be picked up by the most unlikely person imaginable:
>   Bilbo from the Shire!

Sauron was already rising well before Gandalf joined up with Thorin. And the Ring had abandoned Gollum some time before Bilbo found it.

Comment: Do we know how much time there was before Bilbo arrived it had abandoned Gollum?  It doesn't seem likely that Gollum would go very long without noticing its absence...

Comment: @Nerrolken: It's never stated in the books. Assuming Gollum hunts a couple times a week probably no more than few days. In the timelessness of a dark cave one can easily lose track.